# Do GLSL uniform blocks consume components?

Tags: opengl, glsl

If I use uniform blocks in a GLSL shader - do they consume components (from GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS or GL_MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. See [ARB_Uniform_Buffer_Object](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/uniform_buffer_object.txt):

> The amount of storage available for uniform variables in the default
>   uniform block accessed by a vertex shader is specified by the value of
>   the implementation-dependent constant MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS.
>   The total amount of combined storage available for uniform variables
>   in all uniform blocks accessed by a vertex shader (including the
>   default uniform block) is specified by the value of the
>   implementation-dependent constant
>   MAX_COMBINED_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS. These values represent the
>   numbers of individual floating-point, integer, or boolean values that
>   can be held in uniform variable storage for a vertex shader.